# Choosing colors for application

Tags: design, gui, silverlight

What is the best way to choose colors for LoB app, i need to style TreeView, dropdown's, textboxes and a pivot grid, so i need a bunch of colors, tried Kuler but it gives only 6 colors.

So the question is how to do it without designer?

PS. It's a silverlight app.

Comment: Are you just looking for a color scheme, like the [Tango one](http://tango.freedesktop.org/Tango_Icon_Theme_Guidelines)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about User Interface Design.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Talking as an ex-graphic designer - ask yourself carefully if you really need more than 6 colours. Using too many colours is likely to make things look like a mess. There is a reason why tools like Kuler don't suggest large numbers of colours.

If you absolutely require (which IMHO is unlikely) more than 6 then use them as base colours and make lighter/darker variations (something like [this](http://colorschemedesigner.com/) or [this online tool](http://websitetips.com/colortools/colorblender/) will do this - a google for colour scheme or colour wheel and you'll find plenty of tools like this out there).

Comment: So is it ok to have 6 colors and apply them to all of the controls(backround, borders, text) ?

Comment: Yes, take a look at just about any professionally designed site or application and you'll see that the number of colours in use is very limited. If anything, the trend over the last decade has been towards fewer colours and simpler designs.

Comment: In terms of design, less is usually more. Humans are good at picking up subtle design features without realising it.